# Issue with filtering down MySQL database with internal search PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get this search box working to filter down a little dummy database i made, but when i try and search in the search box on the site it gives me an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= ''' at line 1
```

I Have a feeling the MySQL query isn't working properly as "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE City = what is searched" doesn't sound right to me.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("***","******","*****") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("*****");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($POST['search_box']);

    $sql .= "WHERE City = '{$search_term}'";


}




$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


?>
<form name='search' method="POST" action="test.php" >

Search: <input type="text" name="search_box" value="">
<input type="Submit" name="search" value="Search the table...">

</form>

<table width="70%">
<tr>
    <td><strong>City</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Country</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Climate</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Company</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Activities</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Continent</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Terrain</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['City']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Country']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Climate']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Company']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Activities']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Continent']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Terrain']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Comment: And on a side note, you should remember to upgrade to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: When you're concatenating your query you're omitting a space between `Table` and `WHERE`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. This:

```
$POST['search_box']
```

Should be this:

```
$_POST['search_box']
```

Which means you're creating an empty variable (`$search_term`). You'd see this if you had error reporting on. Next time when you develop, put this at the top of your scripts:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1); // or you could use E_ALL
```

And last but not least, you need a space before your `WHERE`:

```
$sql .= " WHERE City = '{$search_term}'";
```

---

**Notes**

- You also need to run the query (*ie, `mysql_query()`*).
- You'd be better off learning [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) / [Mysqli Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) as `mysql_*` is deprecated.

One more thing to note with your search query. You're only going to find an **exact** match to the search query that was submitted. You're best to stick with best practice and search using [`LIKE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php):

```
$sql .= " WHERE City LIKE '%{$search_term}%'";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will use the display errors next time. I am now getting a different error but i believe it is to do with the way i set the database up. Not too sure at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your $_POST variables are named correctly, and there is a space before the WHERE clause. Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";

if (isset($_POST['search_box'])) {

    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($POST['search_box']);

    $sql .= " WHERE City = '{$search_term}'";


}
```

Comment: I now seem to be getting the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE City = 'Rome'' at line 1" I think it's somthing to do with the way the database is setup but i can't figure out what i have done wrong.